# Build Logic into Google Apps Script form when copying to spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I built a simple form using google apps script that allows people to enter information for an upcoming event (date/time, location, cost etc) then click a button and it transfers the information to a column in a shared google spreadsheet and a google calendar. I also figured out how to make it transfer information to multiple spreadsheets, but I'd like to build in some logic that it transfers certain information to one spreadsheet all the time, but only transfers certain information to a second spreadsheet if one of the fields is non-zero. Is there a way to build in logic that will only trigger transfer of information to this second spreadsheet if a person fills in a certain field(s)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the data out of the submit request from the form. Take a look at the following tutorial;

http://www.steegle.com/websites/google-sites-howtos/apps-script-contact-us-form-email

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a standard Google form or did you build it with UI service ?

- In the first option data are always written to the spreadsheet linked with it without any option but you can always let a script delete some items upon answer reception and / or move/copy them to another sheet.
- In the second option you do exactly what you want the way you want